# How to convert ActiveRecord query result into json to feed D3 in a RoR project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I develop an application with Ruby on Rails 5.0

I am building an array of hashes to feed D3, that should look like this:

> var errors = [
>               {index:-1, count:10},
>               {index:-2, count:40},
>               {index:-3, count:20},
>               {index:-4, count:60},
>               {index:-5, count:80},
>               {index:-6, count:30}];

Formatting my ActiveRecord query, I get this result at the rails console:

```
var errors = <%= d3_chart_series_for(this_object).map { |measure| {index: measure.idx, count: measure.score}}.to_json   %>;
```

> var errors = "[{\"index\":-1,\"count\":\"96.74\"},{\"index\":-2,\"count\":\"93.5\"},{\"index\":-3,\"count\":\"91.3\"},{\"index\":-4,\"count\":\"97.05\"},{\"index\":-5,\"count\":\"96.07\"},{\"index\":-6,\"count\":\"96.75\"},{\"index\":-7,\"count\":\"92.03\"},{\"index\":-8,\"count\":\"96.11\"}]"

Nearly good ! How can I remove all these \" to make it readable ?

Is there a simple Ruby method to apply ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because this is in an erb template, you need to mark the json as `html_safe`

```
var errors = <%= d3_chart_series_for(this_object).map { |measure| {index: measure.idx, count: measure.score}}.to_json.html_safe   %>
```

Comment: Great ! I was desperately trying this html_safe method at the rails console with no effect ! It now works fine ;-)